# GA4 how to restart as new session after certain event (web)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I working on a project that need to track event in kiosk, since the "webpage" and browser of the kiosk will no change, which mean the session id will remain the same until timeout. I looking for a way to force new session after certain event.

I find out that has `sessionControl` for UA but don't find any similar thing in GA4.

Tried directly implement  `ga('send', 'pageview', {'sessionControl': 'start'});` as custom HTML in GTM but don't work